# NoSuchElementException while checking a string

Tags: java, http, nosuchelementexception

I am currently writing a basic http server. One of the required functionalities is to display a 400 error if protocol version is 1.1 and there is no Host line.

I have the following scanner that (lines is array that hold the request file)

```
  Scanner scn = new Scanner(lines[0]);
  String command = scn.next();
  String fileName = scn.next();
  String protocol  = scn.next();
  Scanner scn2 = new Scanner(lines[1]);
  String host  = scn2.next();
  String hostline = scn2.next();
```

and then I have the following if statement which is supposed to check whether hostline is empty

```
if ( protocol.equals("HTTP/1.1") && hostline.isEmpty() ) {
String reply="HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\r\n" +
             "Connection: close\r\n" +
             "Content-Type: " + contentType + "\r\n" +
             datestr +
             "<h1>HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request</h1>\r\n";
outs.write(reply.getBytes()); }
```

When I run it and test it I get NoSuchElementException on this line :

```
String hostline = scn2.next();
```

Comment: What is your input to the program?

Comment: It's data from a request file as we're testing it using netcat. The one I'm using to test this if is :

GET /tiny.html HTTP/1.1
Host:
Connection: close

Comment: Your example worked for me. Make sure your input is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it may be that "there is no Host line". How about adding a guard?

```
String hostline = scn2.hasNext() ? scn2.next() : ""
```

Answer (score 2):

[`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) throws `NoSuchElementException` if no more tokens are available. So you should first check if there are more elements with [`hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext())

```
if (scn.hasNext()) {
    variable = scn.next();
}
```